# Outlook Calendar Interop - How to get Senders Email Address?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, interop, office-interop

How do I get the Email address of a Calendar Item (AppointmentItem)?

I assume I go: 
item.GetOrganizer().Address

However this only works if the 
item.GetOrganizer().Address.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olSmtpAddressEntry

if its something else (e.g. an exchange account) how do I get the right email address

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetOrganizer().GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`

Be prepared to handle nulls/exceptions.